# Submenu issues - what's wrong with the hover?

Tags: wordpress, menu, submenu

The site (Wordpress) I'm working on is https://www.mosquitohunters.com/

It's a custom developed theme, so I'm not sure how the menu was set up originally, but when I try to add sub-menu items for a dropdown menu, things get really screwed up.

I can fix most of the styling issues with CSS, however the hover to activate the dropdown has me stumped. It seems like it's being done with javascript or jquery, and it's jumpy and doesn't work properly.

My question is...what is the best way to fix this? Is there something I should be looking for in the .js file that I can deactivate or turn off and just make the dropdown a :hover state instead? Seems like it would make more sense...

Thanks!

Comment: Check this url . http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I understand how to make the menu using just CSS - the problem is once I do that, there's still something that's messing up the hover effect. I assume it's a javascript or jquery thing, but I don't know how to figure that out or remove it. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The website uses this plugin:
https://www.wordpress.org/plugins/megamenu/

Since this file is included: https://www.mosquitohunters.com/wp-content/plugins/megamenu/js/maxmegamenu.js?ver=2.3

Comment: Right. Sorry I should have mentioned that I added that plugin in an attempt to figure out a different way of doing the menu to avoid the issues mentioned above - however it didn't work so that plugin isn't being applied to the menu. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: If you look in app.js there is also a reference to [flexNav](http://jasonweaver.name/lab/flexiblenavigation/). You use it by adding a class 'flexnav' to your site, which is there in line 183 (`<div data-breakpoint="800" class="flexnav">`). You may try to update the flexNav code or read the documentation to look for any flaws.